# Get series playlist from youtube video via API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Youtube now allows a video to be added (by the creator) to one, and only one, [series playlist](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6084043?hl=en). Given a videoId, I'd like to be able to get the id of the series playlist (if a video has one) via the youtube API, if possible. I don't see a way to do it, but I could be missing something. If it helps, I have creator access to the videos in question via the API.